# OpenJDK 8 interpreter debug

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, ide

I want to see how the JVM interpreter works. Can I track function calls using NetBeans or GDB? And how will it be more convenient to do this? I'm interested in starting HelloWorld with the -Xint option and see what steps are taken and see the interpreter source code.

I mean not only the result of the interpreter, but also the interpreter code itself in the HotSpot sources.

I built OpenJDK 8 from source with --with-debug-level=slowdebug option.

Comment: Java doesn't have an interpreter. There is jshell, which looks and acts like one - but still compiles the code to run it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I probably misled you. I meant a JVM interpreter that works in [-Xint](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/7?topic=jaclo-xint-option) mode

Comment: A quick way to inspect the bytecode of class `C` would be `javap -c C`. There are probably 'interpeter visualisers' in existence but I don't know of any personally

Comment: I've never done this but I know it's not straightforward because the JVM generates the interpreter's table when the JVM starts. This looks like a nice resource to start with: https://martin.uy/blog/debugging-hotspot-openjdk-jvm-x86_64-interpreter-in-linux/

Comment: This can help too get a high-level overview of how the interpreter works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823223/how-native-code-is-converted-into-machine-code-in-jvm/56834686#56834686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an idea how JVM interpreter works, you'd better build HotSpot with a C++ interpreter. To do this, pass `CC_INTERP=true` to the `make` command.

This is a simplified version of the bytecode interpreter, written mostly in C++. The primary source file (which implements the main interpreter loop and most bytecodes) is in [bytecodeInterpreter.cpp](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/1bcfb8cc3c6d/src/share/vm/interpreter/bytecodeInterpreter.cpp). You can easily debug this code in your favorite IDE. However, this interpreter implementation is not actually used in a production JVM; its purpose is to experiment and to prototype new ports quickly.

The real interpeter (aka [Template Interpreter](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/RuntimeOverview.html#Interpreter%7Coutline)) is written in a platform-specific macroassembler, its sources are in `src/cpu/<arch>/vm/templateInterpreter_<arch>.cpp` and `src/cpu/<arch>/vm/templateTable_<arch>.cpp`. This interpreter is generated dynamically at JVM startup, so it's not easy to debug it: first, because this is the assembly code; second, because there is no direct mapping from the generated code to the original source files.

`-XX:+PrintInterpreter` option will dump the disassembled template interpreter.

Also, there is `-XX:+TraceBytecodes` flag in debug builds of HotSpot. When enabled, it calls the [trace function](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/1bcfb8cc3c6d/src/share/vm/interpreter/bytecodeTracer.cpp#l86) before executing each bytecode instruction. This can be helpful while debugging the interpreter.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in case of JVM build as zero-assembly / zeroshark the interpreter will be used written in C ++ (bytecodeInterpreter.cpp)?

Comment: @AntKerf Right.

Comment: @apangin can you please guide how to merge operation of two instructions in templateInterpreter / bytecodeinterpreter etc.
I'm working on optimization of bytecode. Any guidance or reference my be helpful for my project